# Database without migration using Laravel 5.4l

Tags: laravel-5.4

I created a database in phpMyAdmin and I want to use it
in my project in Laravel without going through the migration.
will I need the models? and how can I make the CRUD operations without using the models? if I need the models how can I connect each model with its table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use migrations with your database. Even, you don't have to use models to use CRUD - you can use `Query Builder`. But, if you want to get all the power of CRUD - models are recommended. 
Models are "auto-connected" to DB by their names. If you have model `Product` it will be "connected" to `products` table.

If your database structure have different names you can define your table directly in model class:

Example of model `Product` in `Product.php`:

```php
class Product extends Model {
    protected $table = 'my_custom_products_table';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But can I know what is the difference between ```Eloquent``` and ```Query Builde``` ?

Comment: With `Query Builder` you create and run database queries. With `Eloquent` you interact with database using models, where each model has a corresponding table in database.